# Using Google Recaptcha V2 in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, recaptcha

I'm trying to use Google ReCaptcha V2 in my django application. It works when testing locally fine.
I'm now working on deploying/hosting and using my django application on an AWS EC2 instance and now I get the following error in the Captcha box.

`ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key`

I've added the EC2's public DNS `(ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com)` to the list of domains in the Google Admin console but that hasn't resolved the issue. I've also added the eIP in the form of `x.x.x.x`. Is that the proper way to add an EC2 "domain" to Google's Recaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

The public DNS works fine for me. It seems like it has some delays for the reCAPTCHA changes to be reflect on the web server.